# Incompatible magic value 1768713317 in class file

Tags: java

I have a class file and when I'm on the website the following message comes:

> Incompatible magic value 1768713317 in class file "spectrum".

What does this magic value mean? Please help :)

Comment: you are on what website? what does the class file do in the website?

Comment: The website is not public at the moment. May I can send you an email with the url?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327098/java-lang-classformaterror-incompatible-magic-value-218774561

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796484/why-do-we-need-a-magic-number-in-the-beginning-of-the-class-file?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first four bytes of `.class` file (compiled Java binary) should be `0xCAFEBABE` - so called *magic value*.

In your case these are `1768713317` or `0x696C6C65` or `"ille"` (*ille...gal*?) in ASCII. Most likely some JVM tries to open a file thinking that this is bytecode, while it is actually a text file. Maybe class was suppose to be downloaded but the server returns some error instead?

Comment: Sorry for that question, but what does ille means? Where does I have to add the magic value?

Comment: @narf: It means that some JVM tries to load a class that is not really compiled Java, but probably some text file. If you take JPG image and change its extension to .EXE, most likely you'll get some sort of error as well. Sorry, but your question is too vague, can you provide more details?

Answer (score 5):

Magic number is the first 4 bytes in each compiled Java class. This is the structure of a compiled Java class:

```
ClassFile {
    u4             magic;
    u2             minor_version;
    u2             major_version;
    u2             constant_pool_count;
    cp_info        constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1];
    u2             access_flags;
    u2             this_class;
    u2             super_class;
    u2             interfaces_count;
    u2             interfaces[interfaces_count];
    u2             fields_count;
    field_info     fields[fields_count];
    u2             methods_count;
    method_info    methods[methods_count];
    u2             attributes_count;
    attribute_info attributes[attributes_count];
}
```

'magic' should always be equal to: `0xCAFEBABE`. It tells the JVM: "Hey you! I'm a Java class, you can execute my code!". When JVM reads a file and the magic number is not valid it won't execute it.

Comment: That's not the output. This structure was taken from JVM specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1